# What is a good approach for continuous searching for a fresh term of a pattern in a large file?

Tags: tcl

The AUT creates logs for a particular function run and appends the log in a central file.
The line to search in this file is:

```
LatestTimeStamp>MyFunction   SomeStep timeLapsed  SOME_TIME_VALUE
```

Every time the log is generated by AUT, fresh multiple logs of similar pattern are generated as above and its required to extract these fresh logs.

The simple approach I am using is:

## class structure

```
itcl::class clsLogs {
    variable _oldTimeStamp ""
    variable _logRec
    variable _runCtr 0
    method _extractInfoForRun {runType} {
        #read log
        catch {close $fp}
        set log [read [set fp [open [file join [file normalize $env(APPDATA)] Logs Action.log]]]]
        
        #garbage everything before old time stamp and collect all fresh log
        if {[info exists _oldTimeStamp] && $_oldTimeStamp!=""} {
            regsub [subst -nobackslashes -nocommands {.*$_oldTimeStamp[^\n]*\n}] [set freshLog $log] "" freshLog
        }

        #increment run counter for this run
        incr _runCtr
        
        #get all fresh entry lines for reporting timelapsed for different steps of MyFunction in this run
        set freshEntries [regexp -inline -all [subst -nocommands -nobackslashes {[^\n]*MyFunction[^\n]*timeLapsed[^\n]*}] $freshLog]
        
        #iterate and collect time lapsed info for each step of MyFunction for this run
        foreach ent $freshEntries { 
            regexp {(.*?)>.*>>MyFunction\s+(.*)\s+timeLapsed\s+(.*)$} $ent -> timeStamp runStep lapsedTime ;
            puts ************runTyp>$runTyp***********\n\t$ent\n\ttimeStamp->$timeStamp\nlapsedTime->$lapsedTime
            set _logRec(MyFunction_Run-$_runCtr:$runStep,lapsedTime) $lapsedTime
        }           
        
        #reset old time stamp variable for next run
        set _oldTimeStamp $timeStamp
    }
}
```

But this file could be huge and storing everything in one read output variable could result in overflow:

```
set log [read [set fp [open [file join [file normalize $env(APPDATA)] Logs Action.log]]]]
```

Is it somehow possible to use a combination to get the current position of the file pointer and use it to offset to last cursor position and then start reading each time from that position?
What are the Tcl command options for the same?

Comment: So I guess the commands are tell and seek.
`set oldOffset [tell $fp]
close $fp
#wait for fresh logs
set fp [open logpath r]
seek $fp 0 $oldOffset
set freshLogs [read $fp]`
Still testing though ..

Comment: Can't say - there is a loop of execution - this a huge live network elements file that could have 1000s of elements and could be in GBs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this does it:

```
seek [set fp [open $file]] $_fOffset
set txt [read $fp]
set _fOffset [tell $fp]
```

In context:

```
::itcl::class clsLogs {
    private {
        variable _fOffset 0     
    }
    public {
        method _fFreshRead {file args} {
            set options(-resetOffSet) false
            array set options $args         
            if {$options(-resetOffSet)} {
                set _fOffset 0
            }
            seek [set fp [open $file]] $_fOffset            
            set txt [read $fp]
            set _fOffset [tell $fp]
            close $fp
            return $txt
        }
    }
}
```